# Matching values of column to another data frame column and replacing values

Tags: python

I have two data frames. (These are easy examples, my real data has nearly 3,000 rows)

```
>df
 player position nation Mins
 Messi    FW      ARG   3302
 Ronaldo  FW      POR   3029
 Van Dijk DF      NED   500
 Mane     FW      SEN   3088
 Alena    MF      SPA   1592


>df2
 player position
 Alena    CM    
 Ronaldo  ST    
 Mane     LW    
 Van Dijk CB    
 Messi    ST
```

What I'm trying to do is replace the position data in `df` with the position data from `df2`.matching `player` column.

I've tried sorting values of `player` columns on both and then just creating a new position column with `df['pos2']=df2['position']`

but It ends up slightly wrong in some areas of the resulting column.
Which is why I'm looking to do it based on matching a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge your dataframe based on `player` column:

```
>>> df1.drop(columns='position').merge(df2, on='player')

     player nation  Mins position
0     Messi    ARG  3302       ST
1   Ronaldo    POR  3029       ST
2  Van Dijk    NED   500       CB
3      Mane    SEN  3088       LW
4     Alena    SPA  1592       CM
```

Maybe you want to keep history:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on='player', suffixes=('_old', '_new'))

     player position_old nation  Mins position_new
0     Messi           FW    ARG  3302           ST
1   Ronaldo           FW    POR  3029           ST
2  Van Dijk           DF    NED   500           CB
3      Mane           FW    SEN  3088           LW
4     Alena           MF    SPA  1592           CM
```